# Divergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |\sin \omega n|$

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-convergence

I'm looking for a simple argument to show that 
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty |\sin \omega n|
$$
does not converge for $\omega \neq k \pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $\omega = \frac{1}{b}\pi$ with $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b > 1$, then the proof is quite easy because the sequence is periodic with period $2b$.

Now, in the general case (where $\omega$ and $\pi$ are possibly incommensurable), is there a simple argument to establish this proof?

Comment: What is the limit of $\sin \omega n$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ if $\omega \neq k \pi,$ $k \in \Bbb Z$?

Comment: I see, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Exactly. Now what is the necessary conditon for the convergence of a series say $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$? Is it not $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ by Cauchy's principle of convergence?

Comment: You are most welcome @thetouristbr.